# Abrir responseText em uma nova página

Tags: html, ajax

Existe alguma forma de abrir o `responseText` diretamente em uma nova janela? Explico:

O código que uso envia dados para um arquivo PHP que retorna N mensagens. Se eu faço o seguinte `alert(event.target.responseText);` ele me retorna no alert o HTML do retorno, como abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe como abrir esse HTML normal, até na mesma página?

Comment: Você esta usando bootstrap?

Comment: Não, estou fazendo "no braço"

Answer (score 0):

A tag `iframe` permite inserir um documento HTML dentro de outro. Exemplo:

```js
        document.getElementById('meuFrame').srcdoc = 
        "<html> \
            <body> \
                <p>Segundo documento</p> \
            </body> \
        </html>";
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Primeiro Documento</p>
        <iframe id="meuFrame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

o atributo `srcdoc` ( HTML5 ) define o conteúdo do iframe diretamente, creio que seja o seu caso.

Atenção: Tome cuidado com o conteúdo de iframes, pois eles podem rodar JS como qualquer outra página. Se você não confia no conteúdo provido para o seu `iframe`, leia sobre o atributo [sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp).

Comment: Sem usar iframe, não tem como? Pois ficou bem desconfigurada, precisava que "reescrevesse" a página atual inteira, agindo como se fosse uma execução pelo php, nao por ajax. Entendeu?

Comment: @Diego Não, não entendi. Se você quer usar direto o conteúdo retornado pelo  PHP, porque não montar a página já no servidor ao invés de retornar HTML em um evento e depois interpretar?

Comment: Estou fazendo o processo via Ajax, e preciso interpretar o retorno que o PHP gera, que é o que não estou conseguindo. Pois a única forma que ele retorna é com o responseText, que não gera o alerta como gerava quando fazia sem o Ajax...